# What are the properties in compilerOptions to generate .js file using .tsx file in react-native typescrpit

Tags: typescript, react-native

since from yesterday, I am working on typescript in react native. I have set up the typescript in my react-native project and trying to generate .js file using .tsx file transformation in react native typescript.

tried by changing the properties in tsconfig.json file but not get luck

```
  "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "ESNEXT",
    "module": "commonjs",                     
     "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],                       
     "jsx": "react",                         
    "noEmit": true,                       
   "watch": true,
    "strict": true,                        
   "moduleResolution": "node",              
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,    
    "esModuleInterop": true                   
    },
  "exclude": [
    "index.js",
        "build",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I expect output is to generate the automatic .js file by using .tsx

Answer (score 1):

You can add "outDir" property to compiler options:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build"
}
```

The compiled js files should be in your your **build** folder

Here the full list of all options https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Thank you i will check it once